# Visual basic - get duration of an video file

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a program that plays video files from a listbox. I need the program to read the file duration and then close the program if the video reaches to the end.

Is this possible?

Comment: Well the duration of the video file should be contained in it's header data... depends on the type and codec and some more varables... how do you even play the video?

Comment: to start the video i use: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(*path*)

Comment: Yaeh - do you not know when the last video has been completely rendered?

Comment: Oh - I thought that you wrote a program that plays video files.

Comment: Phee... it is going to be a lot of work...
First you have to know what kind of video files you are playing... then, you might want to read some literature on it... maybe there are lib's to help with that particular format, maybe there is not, then you have to write your own procedure to extract the duration...to close the program when it ends you need to know what programm the shell chooses to run your videofile (again type dependent) and see if there are arguments that support that functionality...

Comment: Looks like it might get too complicated for me. I have been thinking if i can use another language or program to write the data to a text file for example and then read the data with vb program.

Comment: `MediaInfo.DLL` can give you the running time of any media file.  If you are playing the media in a different app, your timing wont be dead on because even if you started the player, there is a load time overhead depending on all sorts of things.  Its not clear which app you want to close though.